# how can i adjust the code to show the double type well

Tags: json, double, octobercms-plugins

I'm working to show double data well in my routes.

From backend I insert the correct numbers but in the route it shows me my number but with other numbers.

As in my two attached images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB5Jn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFdmS.png)

I'm looking for the october documentation but every attempt has failed.

My code in routes.php is:

```
Route::get('api/{lang}/to_add', function( $lang ) {
    $to_adds = To_adds::with( 'image' )->get();

    foreach ($to_adds as $k => $v) {
        $to_adds[$k] = $v->lang($lang);
    }

    return $to_adds;
});
```

Someone who can help me?

Comment: JScript does not have ex. Decimals like C#, so double is not exact for some numbers - there are probably 2 options - work with string or round. Or there are some libraries working with decimals in JS. One of google for JavaScript decimals search https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/ probably PHP should have something similar too.

Comment: Hi I solved.
After a few hours doing tests on the code, I found out that it was the google JsownViewer extension that gave this problem.